# Querybuilder with a 'where' statement can not equal to '@' (For an e-mailadres)

Tags: symfony, syntax-error, query-builder

I'm creating a symfony2 project. I would like to select a user from my database where the user's email equals to a variable. I'm receiving the following error:

```
[Syntax Error] Error: Expected end of string, got '@'
```

I want to execute this function because useremail is the only unique value that is entered. I 'm using the following code:

```
$query = $repo->createQueryBuilder('e')
->select('e.userId')
->where('e.userEmail = ' . $userEmail)
->getQuery();
$items = $query->getResult();
var_dump($items);
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You're not wrapping your email string. Try:

```
->where('e.userEmail = "' . $userEmail . '"')
```

Comment: Getting an error: [Syntax Error] line 0, col 79: Error: Expected Literal, got '"' ... Thanks for answering